# Every Lie group is orientable

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am having some trouble showing that every Lie group is oriented. Here is what I have so far:

Fix a chart $(V,y^1,...,y^n)$ about $e$ and define a smooth $n$-form $\omega_V$ on $V$ by defining $\omega_V=dy^1\wedge...\wedge dy^n$. Next, for each $g\in G$, define
$$
\omega_g:=L_{g^{-1}}^*\omega_V
$$
where $L_{g^{-1}}$ is the multiplication-from-left-by-$g^{-1}$ map (which is a diffeomorphism).
Then $\omega_g$ is the pullback of $\omega_V$ by $L_{g^{-1}}$. Note it is defined on a neighborhood of $g$ instead of at merely one point.

**My question is**: if we define it this way, it is easy to show $\omega$ is smooth, but how do we show $\omega$ is well-defined? Namely, if $\omega_g$ and $\omega_h$ have overlapping domains, how do we show $\omega_g=\omega_h$ on the intersection?

---

Or, if we define **pointwise** $\omega(g):=L^*_{g^{-1}}\omega(e)$, then it is easy to show $\omega$ is well-defined, but how do we show $\omega$ is a smooth form in this case?

I see in a lot of texts that they define $\omega$ pointwise in this way, but none of them explains in details how $\omega$ is a smooth form. I thought about proving it via showing $\omega(X_1,...,X_n)$ is smooth for any smooth vector fields $X_i$. Then $$\omega(g)(X_{1,g},...,X_{n,g})=\omega(e)(L_{g^{-1},*,g}X_{1,g},...,L_{g^{-1},*,g}X_{n,g})$$
where $L_{g^{-1},*,g}$ denotes the differential of $L_{g^{-1}}$ at $g$. I do not know how to show this is a smooth function w.r.t. $g$. The main issue seems to be that $L_{g^{-1}}$ varies when $g$ varies.

Comment: The second approach is the right one.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yeah I see that in a lot of texts but none of the texts contains a detailed explanation. Could you explain how, in the second case, $\omega$ is a smooth $n$-form?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the top form is smooth follows from the very definition of a Lie group: since the multiplication
$$ m : G\times G \to G, \ \ (x, y)\mapsto m(x, y) = x\cdot y$$
is smooth, the differential

$$ m_* :TG \times T G \to TG$$
is also smooth. In particular, let $\iota_0: G \to TG$ and $\iota_1: T_e G \to TG$ be both inclusions (which are smooth). Then

$$ I = m_* \circ (\iota_0, \iota_1) : G\times T_eG \to TG$$
is also smooth. Indeed, we have for each $g\in G$,
$$ I|_{\{g\} \times T_eG} = (L_{g})_*.$$

So $(L_g)_*$ and thus $(L_{g^{-1}})_*$ varies smoothly with respect to $g$.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an answer. I understand everything up to "$I$ is also smooth". Could you help me with the following questions?

1. You restricted $I$ to $\{g\}\times T_eG$, so I guess by $(L_g)_*$ you mean the differential of $L_g$ at $e$, right? So $(L_g)_*$ maps $T_eG$ to $T_gG$?

2. If I'm understanding correctly in 1., then you have shown that $L_{g,*,e}$ varies smoothly w.r.t. $g$, but how does this imply $L_{g^{-1},*,g}$ varies smoothly?